# Warnings appeared after Vtiger CRM has been transferred to new server

Tags: php, vtiger, vtigercrm

We did the steps below:

- Move files to new server
- Take database dump manually and upload it in new database
- Configure config.inc.php file
- Update the Site URL and root directory path

Is there anything I forgot to do that caused this issues? 
[image]

Thank You!

Comment: Hi abejero
if you use linux server then give permission OR Open index.php and write  error_repoting(0); on top of the file

Comment: I had same problem, I exactly forgot how i solved but steps must be checking file permission, checking ownership, checking **config.inc.php**, checking auto generated files and make sure all files moved correctly, and all the required php extensions like mbstring, imap etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether you have the correct php version in your server. You can put a php file in your vtiger root folder with just the following contents: `<?php phpinfo();`. Execute that from a browser and take a look at what the version is. Sometimes warnings are due to incorrect php versions.

Put it both in the old and new server and compare the outputs.

Comment: Well, yes, but that is something the Vtiger developers should do. Of course, if you have the knowledge and time, you can go ahead and fix the code. But from my point of view that is impractical for various reasons.

Comment: While hiding warnings does not work, I've found out that we just overlook the php version. Using the `phpinfo()` allows me to compare what php version we used in old server and compare it to our new server. We make the new server php version the same with old server and boom, CRM works. Thanks

Comment: Glad it is working! I edited the answer according to your findings. phpinfo() is always useful in this kind of cases :)